# Slow flash cs5 compilation

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, compiler-construction, flash-cs5

I am developing a RIA with Flash Professional CS5. Although there are not many class, it takes 1 minutes to compile. This slowness breaks quick code&test cycle. I do not know how to speed up the compilation time. Almost every as-3 class has a corresponding MovieClip in the library. Is it because of this? Also there are so many graphical item in the library. Are those slow compilation? Or What is your advice to speed up the compilation time?

Comment: If the many graphic items you mention are bitmap images (for example imported PNG images) I believe it can add quite a lot to the compile time, when the images are compressed and included in the resulting swf file. Lots of embedded fonts and character sets can also take long to include in the swf. Flash Professional CS5 doesn't do "incremental compilation", as opposed to Flash Builder. Flash CS5.5 is the first Flash CS IDE version that has some "incremental compilation", but only for sounds and fonts, as I understand it. See for example http://everythingfla.com/courses/video/32/263

Comment: I would recommend using the command line compiler with an IDE. Instead of using generalization/subclassing MovieClips in Flash directly, try to compile all visual assets into a .swc file then use the exported symbols (with generated code) via composition. If you're using external libraries, also try to use .swc files. The idea is they're pre-compiled libraries, so when you compile the project, you're recompiling only the .as files.

Answer (score 2):

1. Disable Warnings Mode. File -> Publish Settings -> ActionScript Settings
2. Use lower JPEG quality. File -> Publish Settings
3. Disable Compres Movie. File -> Publish Settings
4. Disable Include XMP metadata. File -> Publish Settings
5. Disable (if you enabled before) Generate size report. File -> Publish Settings
6. Optimalizate your as code.

And don't forget to put it all back when you finish testing.

Answer (score 1):

One advice I can give you is to go to Publish Settings/Flash and turn off "Compress Movie". I have a feeling it will save a couple of seconds...

Other then that, I've learned to live with it... The worst is when you are working with a huge framework like away3d...

Answer (score 0):

I've found that images, audio and video can really increase the compilation time. Can you use placeholders until you get your code finished?

Comment: especially if the images are big and using compression

Answer (score 0):

Are you using embedded fonts?  Embedding an entire font set can add a huge amount to both compilation time and SWF size.  Be sure to only embed characters that you are going to need.

Comment: recompiling with a font might take a while, I wonder if using an swc with fonts already compiled would speed it up.